# How to get views by people that are subscribed to your channel?

Tags: youtube-analytics-api

I was surprised to not find a subscribed dimension listed given how prominently this pivot is featured in the analytics UI.

The insightTrafficSourceType dimension will give you people that arrived at your video through various 'subscriber' entry points, but this isn't the same as views by subscribers.

Is there another way to do this?

Context: I'm looking into understanding how our content is doing at getting subscribers over time and I'd like to show the team subscribe rate (new subscribers gained / unsubscribed views)